# Saving many to many relationship tables in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I use Asp.Net MVC, Entity Framework. I have a form it looks like below.

[image]

Here,  dropdownlist is filled from a table(types). Checkboxes is filled from another table(test). Tables are like below:

```
public class Types 
{
    public int TypesID{get;set;}
    public string TestName { get; set; }
    public string TestExplanation { get; set; }
    public int TestTime { get; set; }
}

public class Tests
{
    public int TestID{get;set;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class Types_Tests
{
   public int Types_TestsID{ get; set; }
   public int TypesID { get; set; }
   public int TestsID { get; set; }

   public virtual Types Types { get; set; }
   public virtual Tests Tests { get; set; }
}
```

Types_test table is relation table between Types and Tests. When I click Kaydet button, it shuld save type and checked tests. I made this operation using ViewBag, javascript and hdnvalue.I added checked checkboz values to a hdntext. I made saving process like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string drpType, string hdntesttypes)
    {
        var TypeList = Types.GetAll();
        ViewBag.TypesList = new SelectList(TypeList, "Id", "Name");

        var testypeList = testTypes.GetAll();
        ViewBag.TestTypesList = new SelectList(testypeList, "Id", "TestName");


        GenericRepository<TestDisabledTypes> testDisabledRepository = new GenericRepository<TestDisabledTypes>(_context);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdntesttypes))
        {
            string[] disabletypesArray = hdntesttypes.Split(',');

            using (TransactionScope trns = new TransactionScope())
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < disabletypesArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    Test_Types types = new Test_Types ();
                    types.TestTypesID = Convert.ToInt32(disabletypesArray[i]);
                    types.TypesID = Convert.ToInt32(drpType);
                    testDisabledRepository.Insert(types);
                }

                trns.Complete();

            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

It wokrs. But I search better solution for this process. Can someone give me any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need additional attributes for your entity class, you don't need create link table.
Just define the following class, and EF will generate the link table for you automatically.

```
public class Type 
{
    public int TypesID{get;set;}
    public string TestName { get; set; }
    public string TestExplanation { get; set; }
    public int TestTime { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public int TestID{get;set;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Type> Types {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: How can I take relationship betwwen tables in that case.

Comment: you don't need to, you work with objects, not work with relationships directly. That's the EF's approach

Answer (score 0):

Well, in `EntityFramework` if you want to create a many to many relation object you need to create new object of "linking" entity. Unfortunately, it is not possible to add first object, add second object and say "Guys, you are in many to many relationships. Are you happy then?" :) You need to create relation object, set appropriate fields in it (I think these are ids of two objects itself) and add it to relation collection (entity) in your model. But before doing so **you need to be sure that objects with data you are linking with are already exists in database**. Otherwise you'll get an error

Also it's not necessary to create manually transaction because EF does it for you automatically each time you get/save your data